# Filtering Jackson's JsonNode element based on attribute values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm parsing a json using Jackson's JsonNode. My json structure looks like this (let this be variable rawJson):

```
{
    <some fields...>,
    "results" : [
            {
                "name" : "name1",
                "data" : ...,
                "values" : 13
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "name2",
                "data" : ...,
                "values" : 20
            },
            .
            .
            .
            {
                "name" : "name_n",
                "data" : ...,
                "values" : 151
            }
        ]
}
```

in Java:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode results = mapper.readValue(rawJson, JsonNode.class).get("results");
```

How can I get the particular JsonNode element by filtering the attribute `name`? How about if I want to get JsonNode elements whose `value` greater than X? Can I accomplish these without looping through the `results` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forEach(Consumer c)` (JDK 1.8+) function of `java.lang.Iterable` to perform list iteration. This method takes a `Consumer` instance which process all the values in the list. This approach can be extended to take a filter while iterating as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.json");
    try {
        JsonNode node = om.readValue(in, JsonNode.class).get("results");
        NodeFilteringConsumer consumer = new NodeFilteringConsumer(new NodeFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean apply(JsonNode node) {
                //Filter for node with values greater than 20.
                return node.get("values").asDouble() > 20;
            }
        });

        node.forEach(consumer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static interface NodeFilter{

    boolean apply(JsonNode node);
}

public static class NodeFilteringConsumer implements Consumer<JsonNode>{

    private NodeFilter f;

    public NodeFilteringConsumer(NodeFilter f) {
        this.f = f;
    }


    @Override
    public void accept(JsonNode t) {
        if (f.apply(t)){
            //Only filtered records reach here
            System.out.println("Filter applied on node:" + t);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm restricted to Java 7 for the meantime.

Comment: In such case, I think you will have to write a for each loop for iterating all JSONNode of results. You can re-use the NodeFilter interface though inside the for loop.

Comment: this solution does not prevent Jackson from having to parse the entire payload. Perhaps this is what the OP wanted, so not saying it's a bad answer but I was actually looking for "how to skip the actual parsing of data when a certain condition does not hold" (this is particularly useful for huge JSON files)